# JSR 303 validation - how to print object before getting it validated by JSR 303

Tags: java, json, rest, bean-validation

JSR 303 validation - how to print object before getting it validated by JSR 303.

how to print an object which we are getting in rest ws controller before jsr validations took place. 
We have restfull ws which accepts json object. the corresponding bean has jsr 303 annotations (@NotNull etc..). this validates the request correctly and shows error message with only that field vlaue(throws exception), however for audit purpose we need to print/log entire object.
how we can print/log entire object.

Comment: are you using Jax-rs or spring mvc to create REST apis?

Comment: I don't know what is your environment but I'd suggest to use servlet `Filter` for that. If you're Spring MVC user, you can try to use interceptors.

Comment: Does this validation happen without explicitly calling validate method?